# Entity Framework - Use Web.Config Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

Setup - ASP.Net Web Application referencing a separate project which contains the dbml(soon to be edmx) and business logic classes.

I've been using Linq-To-SQL for a few years now and have been using the same setup as is described here for connection string passing from the web.config.

[Can the provider connection string of Entity Framework be substituted with a DB connection string already defined in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876880/can-the-provider-connection-string-of-entity-framework-be-substituted-with-a-db)

So we have added another object context partial class and passed in the connection string using the constructors.

But this has the irritation of forcing me to manually delete the two constructors from the top of the dbml designer class every time it is rebuilt. We are moving to entity framework soon.
Is the same method recommended for EF? And do you still have to manually remove the two constructors on each rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

You can find any specific connectionstring you want there. This is dependent on which type of database you are using, I can't explain further because I don't know which one you have.